# La sirena della polizia

Tags: word-usage, etymology

Perché il dispositivo usato per dare un allarme o un segnale viene chiamato *sirena*?

***[Sirena](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/sirena.php):***

> - Apparecchio generatore di segnali acustici di grande intensità, essenzialmente costituito da un disco girevole, mosso velocemente da un motore a vapore o elettrico, che spinge con forza l'aria attraverso una serie di ugelli, provocando vibrazioni tanto più intense quanto più velocemente gira; è usato spec. da veicoli di impiego urgente e in alcune aziende industriali come segnale di inizio e fine dell'orario di lavoro: ***la sirene delle navi, dell'autoambulanza, dei vigili del fuoco; le sirene delle fabbriche***.

C'entra con il mitologico canto delle sirene? Il suono delle odierne sirene è tutt'altro che melodioso.

Comment: C'è da considerare che la sirena della polizia è elettronica e produce due toni alternati; le prime sirene erano meccaniche e producevano un solo tono. Quelle usate nelle basi militari sono a motore diesel o elettrico ed emettono una frequenza sinusoidale di intensità prima crescente e poi calante. Sentendo quest'ultime ogni giorno da alcuni chilometri di distanza e con tanto di eco ci si fa un'idea del perché si chiamino così.

Answer (score 3):

A quel che dice il [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sirena2/), sì, c'entrano le sirene mitologiche, ma non tanto per l'armonia del canto quanto «per allusione alla capacità delle sirene mitologiche di richiamare l’attenzione».

Answer (score 2):

Questo articolo di [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_%28alarm%29#History) spiega che i primi apparecchi generatori di segnali acustici chiamati "sirene" erano strumenti musicali. Il Barone Charles Cagniard de la Tour inventò uno strumento capace di produrre suono sott'acqua come le sirene mitologiche e per questa ragione lo chiamò ["sirène"](https://books.google.es/books?id=weA3AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA167&hl=en#v=onepage&q=sir%C3%A8ne) in francese.